# How to get input from Entry and set it as the text in a Label

Tags: python, tkinter, label, tkinter-entry

how do I get the Input from an Entry widget and set it as the text in a label widget.

I have tried the following:

```
l_one = Label(window, text= lambda: self.entry_1.get())
l_one.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
```

To be honest, I didn't think it would work but it was all I could think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a label to have exactly what was input in an Entry widget, you can have them share the same value for the `textvariable` attribute:

```
theVariable = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(..., textvariable=theVariable)
tk.Label(..., textvariable=theVariable)
```

With that, you don't have to do anything else -- no callbacks, no bindings, no buttons. Whenever you type in the entry widget then the label will automatically update.

Answer (score 1):

An example could be the following:

```
def callback(*args):
        lbl = Label(root,text=e.get(), width=20).grid(row=1, column=1)    

myLabel = Label(window, text='Reflecting Entry text here...', width=20)
myLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)

e = StringVar()

myEntry = Entry(root, width = 20, textvariable = e)
myEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)

e.set("Type Something here..")
e.trace("w", callback)
```

This will update the `Label`'s text instantly whatever you type in the `Entry` widget.

Comment: what does     e.trace("w", callback)    do? I get the error callback is not defined?

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot to include the callback function

Answer (score 0):

I binded a callback function in every keypress event. Inside the callback function, the current content of label is appended by the last key pressed.

The only problem is when you pressed backspace, the backspace character is also printed and deletion is not performed yet. Another backspace press will remove the character before the printed backspace character. And so on.

Thus, deleting everything from the entry widget leaves the backspace character there. I'll leave that to you.

Another solution is to use a button, then every button click will update your label. But I think what you want is an automatic update every time a key is pressed.

So, I created a script that meets your question's needs.

**Here is the working script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()

entry_1 = Entry(window, width=45)
entry_1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

# appends current content of l_one with the new pressed key value
def callback(event):
    l_one.config(text=entry_1.get() + event.char)

# binds callback to every keypress
entry_1.bind("<Key>", callback)

l_one = Label(window)
l_one.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

**Good luck!**